# Finding unused space for a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, 2d

In a canvas of width * height pixels, there are a number of polygons.
I have to insert a rectangle which center has to be as close as possible to a specific pixel.
But the rectangle cannot intersect with any of the existing polygons.

I could do it with a square because I would draw the polygons with a strokeWidth equal to the size of the square, and then find the closest point that has no color by checking every point.

This function can check if a rectangle can be drawn without intersecting another polygon : http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm#Anchor-intersectPolygonRectangl-23720

But it would be too CPU intensive to do this for every point (as center of the rectangle).

EDIT: replaced the strokeWidth trick by this line drawing method (w, h are half height, width of the rectangle)

```
function _addSegment(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    if (y2 >= y1) {
        if (x2 >= x1) {
            ctx.moveTo(x1 - w, y1 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x1 - w, y1 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x1 + w, y1 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 + w, y2 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 + w, y2 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 - w, y2 + h)
        } else {
            ctx.moveTo(x1 - w, y1 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x1 + w, y1 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x1 + w, y1 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 + w, y2 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 - w, y2 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 - w, y2 - h)
        }
    } else {
        if (x2 >= x1) {
            ctx.moveTo(x1 + w, y1 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x1 - w, y1 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x1 - w, y1 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 - w, y2 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 + w, y2 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 + w, y2 + h)
        } else {
            ctx.moveTo(x1 + w, y1 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x1 + w, y1 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x1 - w, y1 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 - w, y2 + h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 - w, y2 - h)
            ctx.lineTo(x2 + w, y2 - h)
        }
    }
    ctx.fill()
}
```

Comment: The size of the inserted rectangle is arbitrary?

Comment: Yes. But I actually found a solution so I edited my question. The idea is to call `_addSegment` for each segment of the polygons. This will fill the zone where the rectangle center can't be

Comment: So your problem is solved?